# Using the RibbonSplitButton outside of Ribbon?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, ribbon, ribbon-control, split-button

when I'm using the [RibbonSplitButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonsplitbutton.aspx) outside of a Ribbon, it looses a bit of it's style and the MouseOver-Effect flickers very fast.

Can i assign a kind of style or something to the RibbonSplitButton to get the expected look und behavior? I dont't want to use a ThirdPartyControl...

Comment: I managed to use RibbonButton outside of a Ribbon. It just needed the styles (no ControlTemplate business). I used snoop to copy them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the DevComponents Ribbon for WPF. We use standard WPF ComboBox controls but achieve the DevComponents styling on them by doing something like this...

Notice the syntax for the Style attribute. Perhaps you can get at the styling in Microsoft's RibbonSplitButton by using this approach?